# Cakephp 3 component and model has the same name

Tags: cakephp

because my component, controller and model has the same name:

```
<?php
namespace Plug\Controller;

use Plug\Controller\AppController;

class SettingController extends AppController
{

    public function initialize(){
        parent::initialize();
        $this->loadModel('Setting');
        $this->loadComponent('Plug.Setting');

    }
```

How do I know how to refer to component or model ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Check the manual](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components.html#aliasing-components), almost everything is there. Please consider checking the documentation, it's there to be read.

> **Aliasing Components**
>
> One common setting to use is the className option, which allows you to alias components. This feature is useful when you want to replace $this->Auth or another common Component reference with a custom implementation:

```
// src/Controller/PostsController.php
class PostsController extends AppController
{
    public function initialize()
    {
        $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
            'className' => 'MyAuth'
        ]);
    }
}

// src/Controller/Component/MyAuthComponent.php
use Cake\Controller\Component\AuthComponent;

class MyAuthComponent extends AuthComponent
{
    // Add your code to override the core AuthComponent
}
```